Windows Forms numericUpDown control does not update BindingSource
I have a numericUpDown control bound to a binding source. The bindingsource has a datasource that is a binding list of entities queried using Entity Framework.
_context.Tasks.Load();

_bindingSource.DataSource = _context.VisitTasks.Local.ToBindingList();
numericUpDown1.DataBindings.Add("Value", _bindingSource, "TaskNameID", 
                                false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

As expected, when the current item of the binding source changes, the value of numericUpDown also changes.
However, changing the value in the numericUpDown manually and then shifting focus to another control does not change the binding source.
Rather the numericUpDown goes back to the original value of the current item of the binding source.
I need to be able to manually change the numericUpDown value and have the binding source be updated accordingly.
Here is the entity model:
public partial class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TaskNameID { get; set; }
}


You should see, in the Output pane of VS, something like Invalid Cast Exception, since you're trying to set an int? with a decimal value. Change the formatting option in the binding to true. Then, if the property can actually have a null value, you have another issue, since the Control doesn't support this

I typically implement the Format and Parse events on the control's DataBinding object. This way I can inspect the actual value passed in and out of the control at binding time, and see why the binding fails.
